# Chatter Email Settings - package.xml

Tags: chatter, package.xml

I would like to export Chatter Email Settings via MDAPI (mainly Sender - From Name and Email Address), but I can't find the proper type name. ChatGPT suggested EmailServicesConfig, but retrieve doesn't download anything and I can't find any mention about this metadata:

```
<types>
    <members>ChatterEmailSettings</members>
    <name>EmailServicesConfig</name>
</types>
```

In package.xml name = Settings I didn't find any mention about this setting. In ChatterEmailsMDSettings, the same situation. Does anyone know, where can I find it? Or is it even retrievable via MDAPI?

Thanks for answers.

[image: Chatter Email Settings in Setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package.xml tags are as per below, however the From Name and Email Address does not get extract so assuming this would require to be updated manually.

```
<types>
    <members>ChatterEmailsMD</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
</types>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have checked all Settings members and I didn't find it at all, even in ChatterEmailsMD member. [Official page about unsupported metadata types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm) doesn't tell anything about it. As you answered, just probably it needs to be set manually.